# Why check oil when engine is at operating temperature?

Tags: oil, vw, golf

The owner's manual to my VW Golf Mk7 states

> **With the engine at operating temperature**, park the vehicle on a level surface to ensure that the engine oil reading is correct.

Why is it important for the engine to be at operating temperature when checking oil level?

Comment: Related: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/41603/how-long-should-the-engine-be-off-until-checking-oil-level

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**tl;dr: This procedure checks the oil "reserve" remaining in the pan after all moving parts are lubricated.**

This procedure is purely vehicle dependent.  For example, on my car, I'm supposed to check the oil when the engine is cold.

In asking you to check when the engine is hot, the oil will not be pooled in the oil pan.  Instead, it will have been fully circulated to all the moving parts that badly need that oil to function.  As a result, you'll be checking the oil reserve that remains in the pan.

Note, this oil isn't extra.  Among its many functions, oil is also carrying some of the heat load of the engine.  All those hot moving parts get the oil in contact up to painful temperatures.  An "excess" allows the oil to absorb more heat without burning completely away.  The oil in my car leaves the block, passes through an oil cooler and then to the oil pan before circulating back into the fray.

*Note: I can also check the oil in my car when hot by using different marks on the dipstick.  I prefer the cold procedure so I can confirm total oil.*

Comment: Thanks! So would I be right in thinking that, if I checked the oil when the engine is cold, the dipstick will effectively over-read?

Comment: @Flup, yes, if you incorrectly used the same marks, you'd think that your car was badly overfilled.  I suspect that your car is like mine, though, and there will be other marks on the stick that can be used for a cold vs. hot reading.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the answer of "In asking you to check when the engine is hot, the oil will not be pooled in the oil pan. Instead, it will have been fully circulated to all the moving parts that badly need that oil to function. As a result, you'll be checking the oil reserve that remains in the pan." is utter BS.

I say this because the next sentence in your owner's manual, that you neglected to mention, is this: "Switch off the engine and wait a few minutes for the engine oil to flow back into the oil pan."  That sentence kind of dispels that notion that you're only checking "the oil reserve", whatever that is.

No, you're checking it hot after waiting for a few minutes to allow the oil to drain back into the pan because hot oil expands in volume vs. cold oil.  True, the expansion is small, but VW must think it's enough to suggest checking the oil hot instead of cold, after an appropriate wait time to allow all the oil to drain back into the pan.

Comment: It's generally considered bad form to open your first post by claiming an experienced mod's answer is BS - but kudos for immediately saying why! ;) You are partly right in that the oil does expand when hot, but allowing those few minutes doesn't allow ALL of the oil to flow back to the sump - some will be left coating the moving parts of the engine (by design - a dry engine is a very bad thing, and most of the wear on a typical engine occurs during the first minute or so after starting from cold, as the oil starts to circulate)

Comment: While oil “does” expand, the *rate of expansion (0.00070) seems largely irrelevant to measuring the level*: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/cubical-expansion-coefficients-d_1262.html — or, what am I missing?

Comment: Ahh, my numbers. Assuming easy-math 70-250F (21-121C) oil temperature changes, that’s 0.0007/C * 100C = 0.07.. or 7%. So, conservatively, 4–7% seems like a reasonable volume increase of fresh engine oil. This also agrees with a few other posts :)

Comment: Then there is the argument of how much this noticeable, which probably depends on specific application including the total amount of oil, the sump/shape at the point of oil measurement, and temperature related expansion of the sump itself, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As your engine sets overnight your oil gets colder and becomes just a bit thicker and does not move as freely as when it is warm.  When the engine is warmed up the oil is softened and gives a better more settled reading as to the actual amount of oil in your motor.

Comment: This doesn’t explain why a cold engine oil will read *less* than hot engine oil, after the engine has been sitting off for a few minutes. The oil will be completely “settled” as it cools down, and the process of measuring does not require the oil being moved so viscosity should not be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Most servo attendants will offer to check your oil when engine is hot.Some will even show
you the dipstick to validate claim engine needs oil.Oldest trick in book to sell you more oil.It is then overfull causing a smoky exhaust.Always check on level ground when cold to
give accurate reading.Conversely auto-trans fluid should be checked on level ground in
park or out of gear with engine running.

Comment: How does this correspond to the previous answer which states that checking while hot is mandatory for some vehicles?